# Basic SQL-server support question

Tags: sql-server, restore

I'm facing the most basic SQL-server support question:
I'm developing an application, based on a certain database, and my customer is using that same database structure (same name, same structure, but obviously different content).
Now I would like to copy the customer database and investigate it at my desk, without destroying my own database. I start by taking a backup of the customer's database and copy that backup on my PC.
Ok, fine, but now what?

- If I do a normal restore, my own DB gets destroyed.
- If I create another DB and use this DB as the destination of the restore action, then I get following error message:

  ```
    Restore of database 'From_Backup_Customer' failed.
    ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: The backup set holds 
      a backup of a database other than the existing 'From_Backup_Customer'
      database. (Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended)
  ```

This is such a basic issue, I can't believe there's not an obvious solution for that, but what?

Answer (score 4):

You need the `REPLACE` option that is provided in the `WITH` section of the `RESTORE DATABASE...`  command.

> **REPLACE**
> Supported by: RESTORE
> Specifies that SQL Server should create the specified database and its related files **even if another database already exists with the same name**. In such a case, the existing database is deleted. **When the REPLACE option is not specified, a safety check occurs. This prevents overwriting a different database by accident.**

<sup>***Reference:** [Restore arguments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/restore-statements-arguments-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) (Microsoft | SQL Docs)*</sup>

Your error message is stating that:

> ```
> The backup set holds a backup of a database other  
> than the existing 'From_Backup_Customer' database.
> ```

On the assumption that the customer's database is called `CustomerDatabase` then the backup file contains a backup set for that database. You can check the information in the backup with:

```
RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM DISK = 'D:\Backup\CustomerDatabase.bak';
```

<sup>***Reference:** [RESTORE Statements - FILELISTONLY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/restore-statements-filelistonly-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) (Microsoft | SQL Docs)*</sup>

...and also have a look at:

```
RESTORE HEADERONLY FROM DISK = 'D:\Backup\CustomerDatabase.bak';
```

<sup>***Reference:** [RESTORE Statements - HEADERONLY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/restore-statements-headeronly-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) (Microsft | SQL Docs)*</sup>

When you have all the information together, then you possibly want to either:

- ...check the option to **Overwrite the existing database (WITH REPLACE)** in the GUI of SSMS  ensuring you select the **From_Backup_Customer** as the database name, before you click on **OK**,
- ...or in case you are using a script just add the option `WITH REPLACE` option.

This will look a bit like this:

```
USE [master]
RESTORE DATABASE [From_Backup_Customer] 
    FROM  DISK = N'D:\Backup\CustomerDatabase.bak' 
    WITH  FILE = 1,  
    MOVE N'CustomerDatabase' TO N'D:\From_Backup_Customer.mdf',  
    MOVE N'CustomerDatabase_log' TO N'D:\FromBackup_Customer_log.ldf',  
    NORECOVERY,  
    NOUNLOAD,  
    REPLACE,  -- <== This is the REPLACE option
    STATS = 5;
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are going to restore a database which does not exists in backup set. To see what is the logical name of database in the backup set:

```
RESTORE FILELISTONLY   
FROM DISK = 'filename.bak'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use T-SQL directly instead of the GUI to do the restore. You can script the RESTORE command from the GUI. If you add that RESTORE command to your post, we have something to go on.

Anyhow, the error message suggests that the database name you try to restore into already exists, and a type of safety check by MSSQL steps in so you don't overwrite something by mistake.

If this is the case (which, again, the error message is saying), then your options are:

1. Delete the existing database named "From_Backup_Customer" befor the restore, so it doesn't exist.
2. Use the REPLACE option to the RESTORE command. This is available as a checkbox in the RESTORE GUI.

Answer (score -1):

A colleague has provided me with a solution: simply create another SQL-server server. I don't know the exact tool he used for doing that, but the result in the Microsoft SQL-server Management Studio looks as follows:

[image]

Comment: That's a lot of extra overhead just to restore a single database with a different name. I'd suggestion look at the answer from @JohnKN

Comment: Agreed with Brendan. Also note in doing that there's a *possibility you may be* breaking your licensing agreement with Microsoft.

Comment: @J.D.: how can that be?

Comment: You would have to talk to Microsoft or your licensing var / vendor to answer specifically. We're not able to provide specifics on licensing. But I do know, generally Microsoft follows the stance that **any** production work done on a SQL Server instance, needs to be licensed.